# Powershell form.acceptbutton multiple actions

Tags: powershell

How can I have 2 different actions using the enter key in my Powershell GUI?

I have a Powershell form which has a dropdown menu using the autocomplete function. I have an action on the enter key to run a button.

`$xyz.AutoCompleteSource = 'CustomSource'
$xyz.AutoCompleteMode='SuggestAppend'
$xyz.AutoCompleteCustomSource=$autocomplete
"x", "y", "z" | % {$xyz.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange($_) }`

`$Form.AcceptButton = $GoButton`

When typing into my textbox, I would like to be able to press enter to accept the highlighted option in the dropdown and then press enter again to run my handler $GoButton.

Is this possible?

Comment: What control are you using? New-Object {WHAT IS HERE}

Comment: The dropdown is used for a text box 'New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Comment: Solved this issue. Set the box as a Combobox and included an autocomplete. Selects highlighted option on first 'enter' then runs handler on second 'enter'

Comment: @RyanClayton Rather than updating the title of your post, please consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and then accepting that! Might be useful for other people stumbling upon this question in the future (+ you'll get reputation for doing so) ;)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Will do that. Thanks for the tip. Still new to this place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

Instead of using ''New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox', I was able to create a Combobox 'New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox'.

This allows the first press of 'enter' to select the highlighted option and the second press of 'enter' to run my handler.